# Residue of a complex integral at pole z=0

Tags: complex-analysis

I have the following integrand
$$\frac{1}{z^2 - 4z + 1}\,\sin\left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right)$$
Two of the poles are at the zeros of the polynomial denominator. But there is also a pole at $z=0$. How do I calculate the residue at that pole in order to use it in the Cauchy theorem?

Comment: Actually it's an essential singularity at the origin, not a pole.

Answer (score 3):

Actually at $z=0$ it's not a pole, it's an essential singularity.  The residue can be written as an infinite series, but I don't know if it has a closed form.
You can write your function as

$$ \frac{\sin(z)}{z^2-4z+1} \cos(1/z) + \frac{\cos(z)}{z^2-4z+1} \sin(1/z)$$

and use the Laurent series of $\cos(1/z)$ and $\sin(1/z)$ and the Maclaurin series of $\sin(z)/(z^2-4z+1)$ and $\cos(z)/(z^2-4z+1)$.